# Raw Data Sources

Tags: input

Are there any sources of real raw data I can play with for free ?

I don't care what the data is for, as long as there is a LOT of it.

The more (in both volume and broadness of scope), the better. :)

//Edit to add -- Text data, binary data, images, doesn't matter what it is. A note about the type is nice though.

Comment: If you don't care about the type or content, why not just randomly generate it?

Comment: If we want some data for use in a demo or a training course it's nice if the data is meaningful to human beings.  It is also jolly hard to randomly generate things like foreign keys.  Life is much easier when we have a set of data with the keys already built in.

Comment: I'm currently working on a data generator product which generates foreign keys and many-to-many tables - it's not that hard. The generator, which will be FOSS, should be ready for release in a week or so.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: It depends to some extent on what the data is for. For example, it's helpful if there are some correlations in the data if you're making a training set for a genetic algorithm, or testing a Markov chain or other trend finder. A truly random dataset has quite different statistical properties from most data generated from the real world.

Comment: The generator I'm working on allows you to skew the data to meet real-world criteria. For example, you can specify that that you want a table of names to contain 30% female and 70% male names.

Answer (score 2):

The Federal Aviation Authority publishes its Aircraft Registration database online.  This contains hundredds of thousands of records.  Two caveats.  The Addresses are American (which probably won't bother you) and the Onwers mix indiduals with companies (which might).  Still it's a decent source of data with built-in application logic.

Download it from [the FAA website](http://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/aircraft_certification/aircraft_registry/releasable_aircraft_download/).

Answer (score 1):

[Astronomical star catalogs](http://ad.usno.navy.mil/star/star_cats_rec.shtml) are pretty huge; they contain information on millions of stars, usually in text table format. Most of them are freely available.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Stack Exchange data dump](https://data.stackexchange.com/help).

Also I've seen some people extracting massive amounts of data from Twitter via its API. Can't find the link now though...

Comment: The link is no longer working :-(